# Attempting to save subdocument update, deletes the parent

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am attempting to save an update to my subdocument, but when I save the parent document disappears (thus loosing all the data including the update).

Here is my route:

```
router.put('/input/:parentid/:childid', urlencodedParser, function(req, res, next){ 

    // Update Already Created Incident

       async function update(id){
          let checkedUnits = [];
          let timeEntries = [];
          recall = [];

          units.forEach(unit => {
             if(req.body[unit.id]){
                checkedUnits.push(unit._id);
             }
          });
          // console.log(personnel);
          personnel.forEach(person => {
             if(req.body[person._id]){
                let PERSON = {person: {personId: person._id}}
                recall.push(PERSON);
             }
          });
//===================FIND PARENT DOCUMENT===================================//
         CallData.findOne({_id: id}, (err, doc)=>{

//====================TARGET CORRECT SUBDOCUMENT by id =====================//
            subdoc = doc.incidents.id(req.params.childid);

//===========================UPDATE DOCUMENT=============================//
            date = moment(req.body.dispatchDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
            doc.date=date,
            subdoc.incidentNumber = req.body.incidentNumber;
            subdoc.callType = req.body.callType;
            subdoc.times.dispatch = moment(req.body.dispatchDate).format('MM/DD/YY')+' '+req.body.dispatchTime;
            subdoc.times.clear = moment(req.body.clearDate).format('MM/DD/YY')+' '+req.body.clearTime;
            subdoc.address.placeName = req.body.locationName;
            subdoc.address.streetAddress = req.body.streetAddress;
            subdoc.address.apt = req.body.apt;

            if(req.body.disposition !== "Choose..."){
               subdoc.disposition.selected = req.body.disposition;
            }

            subdoc.disposition.typed = req.body.other;
            subdoc.units = checkedUnits;
            subdoc.recall = recall;

//==============Save Document===============//
            doc.save(err=>{if(err){console.log(err)}); //<==============No error thrown here.
            res.json(doc); //<==================Produces a correct json of the updated doc.
         });
   }
   update(req.params.parentid);
});
```

Once the above runs on a document it disappears from the database. I am not sure why doc.save is deleting the doc.

I have tried using async/await, and CB. I am unsure how else to select the correct subdocument in the subdocument array. Mongoose's docs say to do the ```parent.sub.id(_id)`` to select it but I have a feeling this is where I am going wrong.

Thank you for any insight.
-Adam

Comment: Can you move res.json(doc) inside the doc.save like this? `doc.save((err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      res.json(doc);
    });`

Comment: @SuleymanSah yes. Still get the same result. The json comes back correct but the parent doc disappears. Also still no error.

Comment: Where does parent doc diseppears? Has it been deleted from the collection?

Comment: Figured it out... I love it when it something soooo simple it is stupid.

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: See below for the fix

Answer (score 0):

The answer was here:

```
 date = moment(req.body.dispatchDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

It was changing the date format and therefore I could not find my data, I thought it was being deleted it was not. Just being changed.

I have corrected the code to:

```
 date = moment(req.body.dispatchDate).format('YYYY/MM/DD')
```

And now I it works beautifully.

Thanks for the help.